# Flask, Blueprint route with defaults and methods, FormDataRoutingRedirect

Tags: python, flask

I have a route that looks like so:

```
blueprint = Blueprint('graphql', 'graphql_v0')
@blueprint.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def graphql_query():
   ...
```

which works fine. I want to add another path with variable, meaning I need to provide a default for the first function:

```
@blueprint.route('/', methods=['POST'], defaults={'component_name': 'app'})
@blueprint.route('/<component_name>', methods=['POST'])
def graphql_query(component_name):
  ...
```

this is crashing with the following error:

> FormDataRoutingRedirect: A request was sent to this URL (http://localhost:3000/graphql?hash=13b94387f3dcac8ad4252eb7ea4aa12b) but a redirect was issued automatically by the routing system to "http://localhost:3000/v0/graphql/?hash=13b94387f3dcac8ad4252eb7ea4aa12b".  Make sure to directly send your POST-request to this URL since we can't make browsers or HTTP clients redirect with form data reliably or without user interaction.

I'm not able to make sense of this error based on my existing code.

Comment: Do you want to make a redirect from `/` to `/<component_name>` with _POST_ data?

Comment: I want `graphql_query` the function to work the same way for both paths. is the second decorator redirecting?

Comment: I mean, why you can not register 2 routes [like this](http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/0IIO40)?

Comment: I guess if that's the way to do it. http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/blueprints/ shows both directives on the one path in "my first blueprint"

Comment: Hm... This is weird, but in my case [example from docs](http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/0IIO4V) works fine. Which version of Flask are you using?

Comment: version: Flask 0.10.1

Comment: I checked the example that I wrote above with Flask 0.10.1. All works fine. I can't repeat your problem.

Comment: I had  the same problem and I know how to reproduce it. I created an issue in Flask repository. You could push it too
https://github.com/pallets/flask/issues/2601

Answer (score 0):

well. whats wrong with this method? (just pass the default value for parameter of function)

```py
@blueprint.route("/", methods=['POST'])
@blueprint.route("/<component_name>", methods=['POST'])
def graphql_query(component_name="app"):
    # ....
    return str(component_name)
```

this code creates a double routed function with `/` (root) and `/<component_name>` (root and component name) as routes and returns the `name` of the `component` that is passed in the POST request.

testing if it works (im gonna use curl, same thing as doing POST in the browser):

```sh
❱  curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:5000/app
app%

❱  curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:5000/
app%

❱  curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:5000/just_a_component
just_a_component%

❱  curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:5000/its_working
its_working%

# and doing a GET will raise an error.
❱  curl http://127.0.0.1:5000/its_working
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>405 Method Not Allowed</title>
<h1>Method Not Allowed</h1>
<p>The method is not allowed for the requested URL.</p>
```

as you can see, for me it works.

go take this snippet and tell me if its working. peace.